# I have completed building an angular application. How to build it to run on server i.e cordova

Tags: angular, cordova, angular5

I have completed an angular application. I ran `ng build` command and I got dist folder. No I want to run in Apache Cordova server. How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to run the build with `ng build` and by default the dist folder will have the compiled files. You should use the option `--production` to reduce the bundle size and perform other optimisations on the compiled files. You can change the output folder to a custom one with `--output-path`.
Then you need to copy those files to your server and configure it to serve the index.html file when the user hits the main url of your site.

Comment: I have done it and I have also used ng build --prod which have reduced my bundle size. I agree with these points. Now I am placing them in cordova server and on opening index.html I am getting a blank page.

Comment: It might have something to do with base href config that is specified in index.html file and from where Angular build all its routes for navigation. I used this to deploy on github pages: `ng build --base-href my-url` and it automatically added the correct url to the index.html file, after that my website worked

Answer (score 0):

1.- You must to use HashLocationStrategy strategies. That's in your app.module

```
import { CommonModule, HashLocationStrategy, LocationStrategy } from '@angular/common';
 ...
providers: [..
    { provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy }]
```

2.-Remove the < base href="./" > in your index.html

3.-be carrefull. it's posible you must to change in your index.html the tags script

```
<script src="....."/>
//change by
<script src="....."/></script>
```

Comment: I have done all those things. Can You please place a sample folder structure of any angular project after performing ng build --prod

Comment: All it's in the same directory: index.html, inline.xxx.bundle.js, main.xxx.bundle.js, ... If I open the index.html with Firefox navigator should show the application. if not, check the console